# How to set single selection for GWT multiselect Listbox?

Tags: java, gwt

I created multiselect Listbox (with parametr true in constructor). How to set him single select mode with multi select View (It looks like multi select but I can select only 1 record )?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation warns about using setMultipleSelect on InternetExplorer not working, so it may be best to recreate the widget to use `false` in the constructor.  But, on other browsers, this should work:

```
listBox.setMultipleSelect(false); //single select mode
listBox.setVisibleItemCount(10); //the parameter is the number of rows you want to be visisble.
```

Again, I think the recommended way would be to create a new ListBox and re-add it, to avoid failure on IE6.

Comment: Yeah, it works fine. Do you know, how it'll be works in IE6? What you mean "create a new ListBox and re-add"? Anyway thanks!

Comment: You probably have to do something like `listBox = new ListBox(false); redoInitialSetup(listBox); panel.add(listBox);` for IE6, instead of just `lisBox.setMultipleSelect(false)` (which works on most browsers).